# Function expression ending with ; vs. not

Tags: javascript, coding-style

When reading others code I have seen functions written both ending with a semi-colon and not ending with a semi-colon.

with:

```
var testFunction = function() {
  // magic happens here
};
```

without:

```
var testFunction = function() {
  // magic happens here
}
```

- ?: Is one more "technically" correct than the other?
- ?: Is there a speed advantage to one?
- ?: Do browsers not care and so it's just a style bleeding over from another language or an old format that used to be required for JavaScript functions?
- ?: #{question I hadn't considered to ask here but you think I should have}

Update: I also found this very useful => https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: I just tested this, and it appeared that in my favorite browser the version without a semicolon was remarkably faster!

Comment: @Marcel, Interesting! What code did you use to test and what were the results?

Comment: you may find the following on semi-colon insertion interesting - http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: Add to the test on your machine/browser... http://jsperf.com/function-assignment-semicolon It's been about the same for me on Chrome 8

Comment: Mike, you did hear the irony in my voice, didn't you?

Comment: @Marcel, apparently I missed it. : )

Comment: @box9, looks like it's broken. : (

Comment: Yeah I don't understand that... worked for a while, maybe the missing semicolons confused it

Comment: So many good answers! Don't know which one to accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At it's root, what you have there is an *assignment* statement, and [according to the Google Javascript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Semicolons#Semicolons), all statements should end in a `;`. Especially *assignment* statements. JSLint requires `;` or else it won't pass.

Comment: +1 for the awesome link to the Google JavaScript style guide.

Comment: could this be the link? https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-semicolons-are-required

Comment: In latest javascript, semicolon is not recommended. Only place it required is in a for loop. Cannot find the style guide link to put it as an answer.

Comment: In latest javascript, most cases semicolon is not required. check this
'https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion'

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to define functions:

```
var testFunction = function() {
  // magic happens here
};
```

and

```
function testFunction(){
  // magic happens here
}
```

I believe it's better to end with a `;` when you define it using a statement (first option), but not as a function definition (second option).

JS Parsers are pretty flexible, so YMMV.

Comment: YMMV == Your Mileage May Vary

Comment: The first example is a function declaration, not a function statement, which is a proprietary thing of Mozilla.

Comment: The first example is used to define in closures, and works in all A grade browsers...

Answer (score 3):

I would consider it technically correct to have the `;` semicolon terminate the function because you are **executing a declarative statement**. Though not required by the grammar, it is generally accepted that variable declarations be terminated with a `;` semicolon. In this case, the "variable" just happens to be a function.

```
// As you do this
var i = 0;

// Also do this
var obj = function() {
  // aforementioned magic
};
```

It may also be worthy to note that, when declaring objects, each field is separated with a comma `,`.

```
var obj = function() {
  magic1 : function() {},
  magic2 : function() {}, // <-- Similarly, comma is optional here...sorta
                          //     See Marcel's comment below.
};
```

Of course, for simple functions declarations, it could be considered "more technically correct" to *not* have it since it is not a linearly executed statement. (See excellent [counterpoint](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Semicolons#Semicolons) in Google style guide, etc) In this case, the semicolon `;` gets interpreted as an "empty" line of code, not an expression termination token.

With simple function declarations, leave it off:

```
function doMagic() {
  // aforementioned magic
}
```

Comment: You probably mean function *declarations* instead of "global functions" and the second one is just a function *expression*; you don't define a closure there (i.e., not closure in strict sense).

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO! Not the trailing comma, not again, IE will create an empty element with horrible results.

Comment: @Marcel, not really, right?? Please tell me that's not true. Please? Like, that was some IE6 bug that the world has moved on past, right. Please, oh please?

Comment: Uhm, I might have been a bit to fast, as this generally applies to arrays, but a quick search revealed that it [also applies to objects](http://blog.bottomlessinc.com/2010/01/ie-bug-dont-put-extra-commas-in-your-js-arrays/) (and replace "array" with "object", there). Also see [this NetBeans bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=164626#c6).

Comment: trailing commas have given me grief in the past when working with IE. Such a failed browser.

Comment: That's disgusting! I picked up the "trailing comma" habit when I first learned Python. Thanks for teaching me something today, even if it was just another example IE ridiculousness!

Answer (score 2):

> Is one more "technically" correct than the other?

No. Technically you're assigning a value to a variable that happens to be a function, just the same as `var x = 10`. You can declare this with or without the `;` and it's equally correct either way.

> Is there a speed advantage to one?

I would be immensely surprised if there was a noticeable difference.

> Do browsers not care and so it's just a style bleeding over from another language or an old format that used to be required for JavaScript functions?

Browsers don't care, it's just a quirk of the language.

> question I hadn't considered to ask here but you think I should have

Which one is more readable, you say?  I personally prefer to end statements with a `;` because it feels right and is more clear about what you're doing. I come from Java-land, where this is required, but even when it isn't I think it's clearer to explicitly end the statement with a `;`, so I include it.

But, as with any code style argument, it quickly becomes a matter of personal choice, and there be flamewars. Proceed with caution.

Comment: It's not only clearer to use a semicolon to end a function expression, it's also obligatory to JSLint and, what's more important, when you're minifying your code.

Comment: @Marcel, good point on JSLint. I "grew up" on C++ where the only times a semicolon legitimately followed a closing `}` where 1) end of class definitions and 2) end of `do...while();` statements. From that background, terminating a function with a semicolon seems superfluous, though not necessarily "wrong".